# WinForms LinkLabel DisabledLinkColor property doesn't work?

Tags: winforms

I've been trying to get a WinForms LinkLabel to use the DisabledLinkColor when the control is disabled (`linkLabel1.Enabled = false;`) but it does not seem to want to use it. For example I set it to Green and when I disable the LinkLabel it turns the text grey. In fact, I have yet to find a way to get the control to use the DisabledLinkColor, but it's possible I'm not using the control correctly?

My scenario is that I need the control to be disabled but maintain the same text color, preferably by just setting the Enabled property to false (not overriding Paint method or adding additional logic to the click event).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And now that I posted on here, of course I figured out how to get this property to work.

```
        linkLabel1.Links.Add(new LinkLabel.Link());
        linkLabel1.Links[0].Enabled = false;
```

You can add links to the LinkLabel and set each one individually as enabled/disabled. It then uses the DisabledLinkColor properly. This does not actually solve my exact scenario since I cannot set the entire control to be disabled. It will still be greyed out text in that case. However, I hope this still sheds a bit more light on how the DisabledLinkColor property works.